# Javascript Insert Row

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML Table consisting of several rows. I am trying to insert rows at a specific position in the table. For example if I mark an already existing row and click insert a new row should be inserted below. At the moment adding rows at the bottom of the table works. What I need is to insert the already build row at a certain position.

Here is my code:

```
function addLine(lineNumberGlobal,columnnumber,insertion)
{
  var newrow = document.createElement("tr");
  newrow.setAttribute('id', globalObj.lineNumberGlobal);
  newrow.setAttribute('onmousedown', "setCurIdG(getAttribute(\"id\"))");

  for (j = 1; j <= globalObj.monthdays + 1; j++)
  {
    //build row cells with content
  } 

  if (insertion == true)
  {
    var newrowinsert = globalObj.bodyGlobal.insertRow(globalObj.currenIdGlobal);
    //this actually inserts a new empty row but I want to append my existing row "newrow"
  }
  else if (insertion == false)
  {
    globalObj.bodyGlobal.appendChild(newrow);
  } 

}
```

Any help would be appreciated ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/insertbefore) DOM method. If you want to insert after the row that you have marked, you would need to use that row's `nextSibling` to find the row after it, and then insert before that.

If I assume that `globalObj.currenIdGlobal` is the ID of the row you want to insert after, that would look like this:

```
var refElement = document.getElementById(globalObj.currenIdGlobal);
if (refElement) { // Being defensive here, you probably know it _does_ exist
    globalObj.bodyGlobal.insertBefore(newrow, refElement.nextSibling);
}
```

That assumes that your HTML is structured with **no** whitespace or similar between rows (since `nextSibling` will return the next node after the row, which can be a text node rather than an element). If you need to be more defensive:

```
function findNextSiblingElement(elm, tagName) {
    do {
        elm = elm.nextSibling;
    } while (elm && (elm.nodeType != 1 || elm.tagName != tagName));
    return elm;
}
```

and then change the above to:

```
var refElement = document.getElementById(globalObj.currenIdGlobal);
if (refElement) { // Being defensive here, you probably know it _does_ exist
    globalObj.bodyGlobal.insertBefore(newrow, findNextSiblingElement(refElement, 'TR'));
}
```

Note that if you pass `null` as the second argument to `insertBefore`, it appends to the end.

FWIW, operations like these can be made a bit easier if you use a library like [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries).

Answer (score 2):

Use `insertRow` to create the row.

Also: Don't use `setAttribute`, it's broken in IE. And an event handler requires a function reference and not a string.

```
function addLine(lineNumberGlobal,columnnumber,insertion)
{

  var newrow = globalObj.bodyGlobal.insertRow(insertion ? globalObj.currenIdGlobal : -1);
  newrow.id = globalObj.lineNumberGlobal;
  newrow.onmousedown = function() { setCurIdG(this.id); };

  for (j = 1; j <= globalObj.monthdays + 1; j++)
  {
    //build row cells with content
  } 

}
```

BTW, you seem to be using the `id` to "re-find" the table rows. Consider keeping a reference to the row instead.

Comment: +1, was writing something similar without all the optimisations :-)